# How to write the three-qubit GHZ state in the Pauli basis?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-state

How can one write the GHZ state defined in *Ket* notation as $|\psi\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|000\rangle +  |111\rangle\right)$, in terms of Pauli matrices $\sigma_{1},\sigma_{2},\sigma_{3}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A direct while brute-force way is by writing state $|\psi\rangle$ as density matrix $\rho$. Then by noticing that $\rho=\frac{1}{2^3}\sum_{ijk}t_{ijk}\sigma_{i}\otimes\sigma_{j}\otimes\sigma_{k}$ for $i,j,k=1,2,3,4$ stands for Pauli matrices and identity matrix, find all the coefficients $t_{ijk}$ by $Tr(\rho\sigma_{i}\otimes\sigma_{j}\otimes\sigma_{k})$. If you are familiar with this method, you might find it's nothing more than *Quantum State Tomography*.

But maybe for special states like GHZ state, we may not use this method and directly find the rule of those coefficients while I can't see it directly.

Answer (score 7):

Summary: The expression you're looking for is:

$$
\frac{1}{4} \left[ (III + IZZ + ZIZ + ZZI) + (XXX - XYY - YXY - YYX)\right]
$$

where Pauli string notation like $XYX$ denotes $\sigma_1 \otimes \sigma_2 \otimes \sigma_1$, for example.

---

To start, we need to write the $n$-qubit GHZ state as an operator, namely

\begin{equation}
|\psi^{(n)}\rangle\langle\psi^{(n)} | = \frac{1}{2}\left( |0\rangle \langle 0|^{\otimes n} +  |0\rangle \langle 1|^{\otimes n} +  |1\rangle \langle 0|^{\otimes n} +  |1\rangle \langle 1|^{\otimes n}\right) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where we use the notation
\begin{equation}
 A^{\otimes n} = \underbrace{A \otimes A \otimes \dots \otimes A}_{\text{n times}}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Taking the pauli matrices to be $\{I, X, Y, Z\}$, we will break this into its diagonal component and off-diagonal component. Looking at the general $n$-qubit case we can rewrite each term of $|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$ as one of these:
\begin{align}
|0\rangle \langle 0|^{\otimes n} &= \frac{1}{2^n}(I + Z)^{\otimes n} \tag{3a-d}\\
|1\rangle \langle 1|^{\otimes n} &= \frac{1}{2^n}(I - Z)^{\otimes n}\\
|0\rangle \langle 1|^{\otimes n} &= \frac{1}{2^n}(X + iY)^{\otimes n}\\
|1\rangle \langle 0|^{\otimes n} &= \frac{1}{2^n}(X - iY)^{\otimes n}
\end{align}

The terms on the right each look a bit like $(a + b)^n$ and $(a - b)^n$, which we would be able to expand using the Binomial theorem for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. However since we are dealing with non-commuting operators, we will have to settle for something that just *looks* like the binomial theorem and see how much we can simplify.

##### Permutations for expressing $(A + B)^{\otimes n}$

Consider a permutation operator $S_\pi$ for some permutation $\pi: \{1, \dots, n\}\rightarrow \{1, \dots, n\}$ which has the effect of rearranging the subsystems of its input according to a given permutation $\pi$. For example if $(\pi(a), \pi(b), \pi(c)) = (b, c, a)$ then the action of $S_\pi$ on a separable operator would be
\begin{equation}
S_\pi (A \otimes B \otimes C) = B \otimes C \otimes A \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Then for two operators $A, B$ with $[A, B] \neq 0$ in general we can write
\begin{align}
(A + B)^{\otimes n} = A^{\otimes n} + \sum_{\pi} S_\pi\left(A^{\otimes (n-1)} \otimes B\right) + \sum_{\pi} S_\pi\left(A^{\otimes (n-2)}\otimes B^{\otimes 2}\right) + \cdots \tag{5} \\
(A - B)^{\otimes n} = A^{\otimes n} - \sum_{\pi} S_\pi\left(A^{\otimes (n-1)} \otimes B\right) + \sum_{\pi} S_\pi\left(A^{\otimes (n-2)}\otimes  B^{\otimes 2}\right) - \cdots \tag{6}
\end{align}

We can combine (5)-(6) to find
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} &\left((A + B)^{\otimes n} + (A - B)^{\otimes n} \right) 
\\&= A^{\otimes n} + \sum_{\pi} S_\pi\left(A^{\otimes (n-2)} \otimes B^{\otimes 2}\right) + \sum_{\pi} S_\pi\left(A^{\otimes (n-4)} \otimes B^{\otimes 4}\right) + \cdots  
\\&= \sum_{t=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \sum_\pi S_\pi\left(A^{\otimes (n-2t)} \otimes B^{\otimes 2t}\right) \tag{7}
\end{align}
where we observe that every term $B^{\otimes k}$ with odd $k$ has been eliminated. This lets us write the following:

\begin{align}
|0\rangle \langle 0|^{\otimes n} + |1\rangle \langle 1|^{\otimes n}  &=  \frac{1}{2^{n}}\left[(I + Z)^{\otimes n} + (I - Z)^{\otimes n}\right] 
\\&= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \sum_{t=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \sum_\pi S_\pi\left(I^{\otimes (n-2t)} \otimes Z^{\otimes 2t}\right) \tag{8}
\end{align}

and$^1$
\begin{align}
|0\rangle \langle 1|^{\otimes n} + |1\rangle \langle 0|^{\otimes n} &= \frac{1}{2^n} \left[(X + iY)^{\otimes n} +  (X - iY)^{\otimes n} \right]
\\&= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{t=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \sum_\pi S_\pi\left(X^{\otimes (n-2t)}\otimes  (iY)^{\otimes 2t}\right)
\\&= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{t=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (-1)^t \sum_\pi S_\pi\left(X^{\otimes (n-2t)}\otimes  Y^{\otimes 2t}\right) \tag{9}
\end{align}

with the final expression becoming the sum of these two parts:
\begin{equation}
|\psi^{(n)}\rangle\langle\psi^{(n)} | =  \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{t=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \left[ \sum_\pi S_\pi\left(I^{\otimes (n-2t)} \otimes  Z^{\otimes 2t}\right) + (-1)^t \sum_\pi S_\pi\left(X^{\otimes (n-2t)} \otimes Y^{\otimes 2t}\right)\right] \tag{10}
\end{equation}

##### Solution for $n=3$

Now we can write out 3-qubit case by just enumerating over Pauli strings with the correct parity. In the sum of (8) we will keep the terms $III$, $IZZ$, $ZIZ$, $ZZI$. In the sum of (9) we will keep the terms $XXX$, $XYY$, $YXY$, $YYX$. Plugging into (10) we get

\begin{align}
|\psi^{(3)}\rangle\langle\psi^{(3)} | = \frac{1}{4} \left[ (III + IZZ + ZIZ + ZZI) + (XXX - XYY - YXY - YYX)\right] \tag{11}
\end{align}

#### Direct Fidelity Estimation

Looking at Equations (10) and (11) we can see that as the system size grows, the GHZ state will continue to have support on a tiny subset of the $4^n$ Pauli strings: There are only terms containing $Z$ and $I$ together or $X$ and $Y$ together, and even among these a large chunk are missing for the parity constraints shown above.

One consequence of this is that you can estimate the fidelity of a GHZ on $n$ qubits using only $O(n)$ measurement configurations ([Gühne, 2007](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2432)) compared to something exponential in $n$ that you might expect. This is a special case of the more general idea of Direct Fidelity Estimation (DFE) ([Flammia, 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4695)) which demonstrated how fidelity estimation could be improved based on how many of the $4^n$ Pauli strings were missing from the Pauli representation of your state. Of course, ([Huang, 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.08953)) brought this way down to $O(1)$ scaling using classical shadows but this is slightly less intuitive than the basic idea.

---

$^1$ This recovers Equation (5) in ([Gühne, 2007](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2432))